# vmap and visual block: how do I write a function to operate once for the entire block?

Tags: vimscript, visual-block

I'm trying to write a simple function that wraps a visual selection of lines with Markdown <kbd>```</kbd> lines. Here's what I currently have:

````
function! MarkCodeBlock()
    " Add Markdown code-block delimiters to begin and end of current visual group.
    execute "normal! `<O```\<esc>yy`>p"
endfunction

vnoremap <leader>_ :call MarkCodeBlock()<CR>
````

It *mostly* works, but it appears to invoke `MarkCodeBlock()` once for each line in the visual selection. As an example, suppose I have the following block:

```
This is not a code line
This is a code line
This is a code line
This is a code line
This is not a code line
```

where the middle three lines are visually selected. On invoking the map sequence, I end up with this:

````
This is not a code line
```
```
```
This is a code line
This is a code line
This is a code line
```
```
```
This is not a code line
````

but I want this:

````
This is not a code line
```
This is a code line
This is a code line
This is a code line
```
This is not a code line
````

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you press `leader _`, you enter command-line mode from visual mode.
If you try to enter command-line mode from visual mode manually, you'll see that Vim automatically inserts this range:

```
:'<,'>
 ├┘ ├┘
 │  └ mark put automatically on the last line of the visual selection
 └ mark put automatically on the first line of the visual selection (see `:h '<`)
```

So, when `:call` calls your `MarkCodeBlock()` function, Vim has automatically prefixed it with a range.
And, from `:h func-range`:

> If `[range]` is excluded, ":{range}call" will call the function for each line in
>   the range, with the cursor on the start of each line.

Because of this, your function is called once for every line in the range.

You have 2 possibilities:

1. Eliminate the range by making your mapping press `C-u` (see `:h c^u`):

   ```
   vnoremap <leader>_ :<c-u>call MarkCodeBlock()<CR>
                       ^^^^^
   ```
2. Make Vim know that the function can handle the range itself and doesn't need `:call` to re-invoke it for every  line in the range. You can do so by passing the `range` argument to `:function`:

   ```
   function! MarkCodeBlock() range
                             ^^^^^
       ...
   endfunction
   ```

---

A few possible improvements/suggestions:

`:vnoremap` is applied in 2 modes: visual and select.
But you're probably interested only in visual mode, because (from `:h mapmode-s`):

> NOTE: Mapping a printable character in Select mode may confuse the user.

And the `lhs` of your mapping contains printable characters.

If you want your mapping to be applied only in visual mode, use `:xnoremap` instead of `:vnoremap`:

```
xnoremap <leader>_ :<c-u>call MarkCodeBlock()<CR>
^
```

---

If your `leader` namespace becomes too crowded, and you need to offload some of the mappings to another namespace, you could use `m` in visual mode. A `m<key>` mapping won't shadow any Vim's built-in command, since you can't put a mark in visual mode.

```
xnoremap m_ :<c-u>call MarkCodeBlock()<CR>
         ^
```

---

Your `MarkCodeBlock()` function is public, which means that its definition could collide with another public function with the same name. You could make it “private” (local to the script) by prefixing its name with `s:` in your definition, and with `<sid>` in your mapping. From `:h <sid>`:

> When defining a function in a script, "s:" can be prepended to the name to
>   make it local to the script.  But when a mapping is executed from outside of
>   the script, it doesn't know in which script the function was defined.  To
>   avoid this problem, use "`<SID>`" instead of "s:".  The same translation is done
>   as for mappings.  This makes it possible to define a call to the function in
>   a mapping.

```
xnoremap m_ :<c-u>call <sid>MarkCodeBlock()<CR>
                       ^^^^^

function! s:MarkCodeBlock()
          ^^
    ...
endfunction
```

---

If an error is raised while the statements in your function are being executed, you may want Vim to stop executing the next ones (this gives shorter stack traces). In this case, you can pass the `abort` argument to `:function` (see `:h :func-abort`):

```
function! s:MarkCodeBlock() abort
                            ^^^^^
    ...
endfunction
```

---

Instead of using `:normal` to add lines in your buffer, you could use `append()` (and `line()`; see `:h append()` and `:h line()`). In general, the latter has the benefit of not making the cursor move.

````
execute "normal! `<O```\<esc>yy`>p"

⇔

call append(line("'<")-1, '```')
call append(line("'>"), '```')
````

If your Vim version includes the patch [8.1.0037](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0037), you can do the same to any buffer, not just the current one, using the `appendbufline()` function instead of `append()`.

---

All in all, this would give:

````
function! s:MarkCodeBlock() abort
    " Add Markdown code-block delimiters to begin and end of current visual group.
    call append(line("'<")-1, '```')
    call append(line("'>"), '```')
endfunction
xnoremap m_ :<c-u>call <sid>MarkCodeBlock()<CR>
````

Comment: Or something like this: `xnoremap <key> :<c-u>'>put='```'<bar>'<put!='```'<cr>`

Comment: +1, `:put` is shorter here. `:put` and `append()` have their pros and cons. `:put` is more handy on the command-line because it's shorter to type. Also, it moves the cursor on the last line pasted. This is handy when you have multiple blocks of text to paste one right after the other. OTOH, sometimes you don't want the cursor to move. Also, it's not silent (so you have to prefix it with `:silent`). If the expression contains double quotes, you have to escape them to prevent Vim from interpreting them as command terminations.

Comment: And it pollutes the expression register (although, usually you probably don't care about what it contains). So, usually I tend to type `:put` in an interactive usage, and write `append()`, `appendbufline()`, `setline()`, `setbufline()` in scripts. But there're exceptions.

Comment: Just wanted to say that after using Vim for probably over a decade, I have only recently gotten deep into Vim scripts, plugins, and other configuration fun. I'm _hugely_ thankful for the time you took to write this response, and find it tremendously helpful. THANK YOU!