# How can I call function in visual mode

Tags: neovim, visual-mode, functions

I want a function to change underline word to little camel for one line.

When I use `<shift+v>:s/_\(\w\)/\u\1/g`, it work fine.

And then I want to make a function to simplify it, `<shift+v>:ToLittleCamel`

```
" underline to little camel
:command ToLittleCamel call ToLittleCamel()
function! ToLittleCamel()
    s/_\(\w\)/\u\1/g
endfunction
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17606/vmap-and-visual-block-how-do-i-write-a-function-to-operate-once-for-the-entire) helps you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a `:command`, I would suggest defining it with `-range` and passing along the line numbers:

```
:command -range ToLittleCamel <line1>,<line2>call ToLittleCamel()
```

This works because when `:call` has a range and its function is not `range`, it execute the function once on every line of the range.

You can also make the function `range` (but keep the call the same above):

```
function ToLittleCamel() range
  execute a:firstline ',' a:lastline 'substitute /_\(\w\)/\u\1/g'
endfunction
```

References:

- `:help :command-range`
- `:help :command-repl`
- `:help <line1>`
- `:help :call`
- `:help function-range-example`
- `:help :func-range`

Comment: It would be nice if your answer also addressed how to adapt the `ToLittleCamel()` function to turn it into a range function. It's possible to get that from the docs, but it would be nice to include it in the answer, for this simple example.

Comment: @filbranden tried from mobile; hope it’s correct :)

Comment: fix: Second arg in example func shoud be a:lastline. It could be a clerical error. (edits must be at least 6 char)

Comment: @Sangria thanks for calling that out; fixed