# Duplicate selected lines programmatically

Tags: vimscript, cut-copy-paste, visual-mode

I'm creating a Vim script and a critical part of it is duplicating the selected lines. To duplicate lines, I have this mapping which works as intended:

```
vnoremap <Leader>d :copy '><CR>
```

But, when inside a function/script, the behavior of `copy` seems different:

```
function Foo()
    copy '>
endfunction
```

**Sample Selected Lines**

```
x = 'alpha'
y = 'bravo'
z = 'charlie'
```

**Expected Result**

```
x = 'alpha'
y = 'bravo'
z = 'charlie'
x = 'alpha'
y = 'bravo'
z = 'charlie'
```

**Actual Result** (lines seem to be copied in reverse order)

```
x = 'alpha'
y = 'bravo'
z = 'charlie'
z = 'charlie'
y = 'bravo'
x = 'alpha'
```

Likewise, running the `copy` command manually against the selected lines works as expected:
`:'<,'>copy '>`

Am I missing something? Are there better ways to duplicate selected lines programmatically? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the culprit. Thanks to Tim Pope's [comment](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/issues/159#issuecomment-1100745945) on my posted issue and the related answer [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17606/vmap-and-visual-block-how-do-i-write-a-function-to-operate-once-for-the-entire#answer-17608).

`copy` here is executed once per line selection which is not the intended behavior (i.e. the reverse order in the duplicated lines):

```
function Foo()
    copy '>
endfunction
```

We want to execute the `'<,'>copy '>` inside the script instead. But, this will duplicate the `N` selected lines `N` times:

```
function Foo()
    '<,'>copy '>
endfunction
```

Effectively, we want to duplicate the `N` selected lines once only. There are 2 options:

- append `range` at the function definition:

  ```
  function Foo() range
      '<,'>copy '>
  endfunction
  ```
- prepend the command with `<C-U>` to clear the selection before calling the function:

  ```
  function Foo()
      '<,'>copy '>
  endfunction

  xnoremap <Leader>r :<C-U>call Foo()<CR>
  ```

Both work as intended!

Comment: Great answer! In the `function ... range`, you should actually use `execute a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . "copy '>"` in the body, which actually works with the range that was passed, instead of the range of the last visual selection. That would make `:1,5call Foo()` or `:%call Foo()` work. See also [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37289/18609) which expands on range functions a bit.

Comment: Right, that would be a nice improvement to handle various scenarios. Thanks!